# How to disable Auto Locking when our metro app is running?

Tags: xaml, asynchronous, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-async

i am developing a metro app in which i fetching some data from service at that moment the device will go to  auto lock since it is un - responsive for long time.

so , how can i avoid this auto locking in the metro app when some process/fetching/syncing is happening with services.

i am not able test this scenario since i am testing it on an emulator.

1) how to avoid auto locking feature in metro app when it is running?
2) What are the various possible ways in which i can do this ?

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try [this](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/04/how-to-keep-windows8-display-on.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj152728.aspx
DisplayRequest.RequestActive method can help.